# How to export HTML table to Excel (xlsx) in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, excel, ajax, jsp

I need to export an html table to Excel with xlsx format in my .jsp file with font edition (I need my headers in bold).

Hello,
I'm trying to do an excel export from html (html table) with font edition (I only need the headers in bold).
I tryed all the options that I have readed in StackOverflow:

1-I used some code and I obtained an xls file(with the headers in bold), my company said to me that it's  not correct.
2-I used the Sheet-JS library and I obtained a xlsx file without font edition (It's necessary to pay for the pro version that allows me to do font edition, my company said no to this).

I put here the code that I'm actually using (I obtain the xlsx file without font edition).

I need some code for my .jsp file that allows me to downoald (with the headers in bold) the html table.

The functions that downloads the html table with xlsx format is TableToExcel and I send the parameter "tableid" from my html button.

```
function TableToExcel(tableid)
     {
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('example1'));
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws1,"Sheet 1");
    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true,  type: 'binary'});
    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'RRHH.xlsx');
}
    function s2ab(s) {

        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        return buf;
    }
```

I only need to introduce some code in this function in order to make font edition (just put the headers in font).